# Not Receiving Push Notifications (And Out of Troubleshooting Ideas)

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have what seems like should be a working push notification in an iOS app. Here's the meat of it. What's ***driving me nuts*** is that everything appears to work, except that my breakpoints are never hit in the message receiver functions; device registration with Google Cloud Notifications is successful, the initialization code appears to work and I even get "Success" messages back from the GCM service.

STILL, I never seem to actually get the message in my app. Note, I'm running it in an iPad connected to my Mac and everything seems kosher/enabled in Notifications settings. Also, I'm using the dev certificate to match the kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:true option.

What could I be missing?

```
import UIKit
import Google

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GGLInstanceIDDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var gcmSenderID: String?
    var registrationToken: String?
    var registrationOptions = [String: AnyObject]()

    let messageKey = "onMessageReceived"
    let registrationKey = "onRegistrationCompleted"

    func application( application: UIApplication,
        didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        //********************************
        //*** Never Hits Breakpoint ******
        //********************************

            print("Notification received: \(userInfo)")
            // Handle the received message

            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,
                userInfo: userInfo)
    }

    func application( application: UIApplication,
        didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
        fetchCompletionHandler handler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        //********************************
        //*** Never Hits Breakpoint ******
        //********************************

       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(messageKey, object: nil,
                userInfo: userInfo)
            handler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData);
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        var configureError:NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
        assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
        gcmSenderID = GGLContext.sharedInstance().configuration.gcmSenderID

        // ...
        // Register for remote notifications
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }


    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

        // Create a config and set a delegate that implements the GGLInstaceIDDelegate protocol.
        let instanceIDConfig = GGLInstanceIDConfig.defaultConfig()
        instanceIDConfig.delegate = self

        // Start the GGLInstanceID shared instance with that config and request a registration
        // token to enable reception of notifications
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(instanceIDConfig)
        registrationOptions = [kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
            kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:true]
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
            scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)

    }

    func application( application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError
        error: NSError ) {
            print("Registration for remote notification failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            // [END receive_apns_token_error]
            let userInfo = ["error": error.localizedDescription]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
                registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
    }

    func registrationHandler(registrationToken: String!, error: NSError!) {
        if (registrationToken != nil) {
            self.registrationToken = registrationToken
            print("Registration Token: \(registrationToken)")
            let userInfo = ["registrationToken": registrationToken]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
                self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        } else {
            print("Registration to GCM failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            let userInfo = ["error": error.localizedDescription]
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
                self.registrationKey, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        }
    }

    func onTokenRefresh() {
        // A rotation of the registration tokens is happening, so the app needs to request a new token.
        print("The GCM registration token needs to be changed.")
        GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,
            scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)
    }
}
```

Message sent to https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send. The payload is arbitrary/copied from a sample.

```
{ 
    "content-available":1,
    "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "<<the registration token resulting from the code above>>"
}
```

...which results in the reply:

```
{
  "multicast_id": 12345...,
  "success": 1,
  "failure": 0,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "message_id": "some ID"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you enable push notification capabilities?

  http://i.stack.imgur.com/BffFp.png

Comment: Yes, though I noticed I didn't enable Background Modes->Remote Notifications, so that helps explain half of my problem. Regardless, it seems like the first handler should hit a breakpoint (since it's supposed to be handling notifications when the app is running). Also, does it matter that the actual bundle ID becomes <<teamId>>.com.company.appname? Would that affect anything?

Comment: are you getting proper response in 'didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken ' ?

Comment: Yes. Token is coming back great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following command in your terminal by substituting your *GCM registration token* and *Server API key*.. this command helps me.

> Please make sure payload dictionary must be **notification** not
>   **data**

curl --header "Authorization: key=”  https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d '{"to”:””,”priority":"high”, “notification":{"title”:”TEST TITLES”,”body":"Wow ! your first message tested.","badge":"1","sound":"default"}}'

Also try checking by app sending in background *CMD + H*

Comment: Sweet! Follow-up question: what if I want to send data such that I open up a specific view? Is "data" used for that?

Comment: Never mind. I figured out that I could send both "data" and "notification".  At any rate, including the "notification" element was what I was missing and it now works. Thanks again!